# Can separable states have quantum mutual information larger than one?

Tags: entanglement, mutual-information, quantum-discord

Consider bipartite (qubit) systems. The *classical* mutual information between a pair of binary
registers,
$$I(X:Y)\equiv H(X)+H(Y)-H(X,Y),$$
is always lesser than $1$ (and non-negative). On the other hand, the *quantum mutual information* of a bipartite state $\rho$, defined as
$$I(\rho) \equiv S(\rho_A) + S(\rho_B) - S(\rho),$$
with $S(\rho)$ von Neumann entropy of $\rho$, and $\rho_A\equiv\operatorname{Tr}_B(\rho)$, $\rho_B\equiv\operatorname{Tr}_A(\rho)$, satisfies $0\le I(\rho)\le 2$.

If $\rho$ is pure, we also know that $I(\rho)=2J(\rho)$, where $J(\rho)$ is the *accessible* mutual information (the one obtained computing the mutual information via the conditional entropy, maximising over the possible measurement choices). Therefore, a pure $\rho$ is separable (*i.e.* a product state) iff $I(\rho)=J(\rho) = 0$.

For a more general *classical-quantum* state, some $\rho=\sum_i p_i \,|i\rangle\!\langle i|\otimes \rho_i$, we have
$$I(\rho) = H(\mathbf p)+S\left(\sum_{i}p_{i}\rho_{i}\right)-S(\rho), \\
S(\rho) = \sum_i p_i S(\rho_i) + H(\mathbf p),$$
and thus
$$
I(\rho) = S\left(\sum_{i}p_{i}\rho_{i}\right)
- \sum_i p_i S(\rho_i) \le
S\left(\sum_{i}p_{i}\rho_{i}\right) \le 1,
$$
because $S(\sigma)\le1$ for any single-qubit state $\sigma$.

These are all examples of separable states with quantum mutual information $I(\rho)\le 1$. More generally, it's clear that a state can give $I(\rho)>1$ only if it has nonzero discord, so a separable state with $I(\rho)>1$ would have to be discordant. But classical-quantum states are separable and can have nonzero discord (with respect to measurements on the second space), but still always give $I(\rho)\le1$. Other classical examples of discordant separable states that are not classical-quantum are Werner states:
$$\rho_z = \frac{1-z}{4}I +z |\Phi^+\rangle\!\langle\Phi^+|
=\frac14\begin{pmatrix}1+z & 0&0& 2z \\ 0& 1-z & 0 & 0 \\ 0&0&1-z&0 \\ 2z & 0 & 0 & 1+z\end{pmatrix}, \\ |\Phi^+\rangle\equiv\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle).$$
These are separable for $z\le1/3$, but as discussed in ([Ollivier, Zurek 2001](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0105072)), have nonzero discord. Their quantum mutual information reads
$$I(\rho_z) = \frac14\left[
 (1+3z) \log_2(1+3z) + 3(1-z)\log_2(1-z)
\right],$$
which is smaller than $1$ for $z\le 1/3$.

Is the above a general feature? In other words, do *all* separable states have $I(\rho)\le1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\rho_{AB}$ is separable then
$$
I(A:B) \leq \min\{H(A), H(B)\}.
$$

To see this first note that
$$
I(A:B) = H(A) + H(B) - H(AB) = H(A) - H(A|B).
$$
Now consider the conditional entropy term $H(A|B) := H(AB) - H(B)$. We will show that it is nonnegative for separable states. Let $\rho_{AB} = \sum_x p_x \sigma_x \otimes \tau_x$ be a separable state and define a classical extension $\rho_{ABX} = \sum_x p_x \sigma_x \otimes \tau_x \otimes |x\rangle \langle x |$, where $X$ is a classical register. Note that $\mathrm{Tr}_X[\rho_{ABX}] = \rho_{AB}$. Now by strong subadditivity of the von Neumann entropy we have that
$$
H(A|BX) \leq H(A|B).
$$
So it suffices to show that $H(A|BX)\geq 0$. Well as $X$ is classical we have
$$
H(A|BX) = \sum_x p_x H(A|B,X=x)
$$
But notice that conditioned on a particular value of $X=x$ the state $\rho_{ABX}$ becomes a product state. It is not difficult to show that for product states, i.e., $\sigma_x \otimes \tau_x$ we have
$$
H(AB) = H(A) + H(B)
$$
hence
$$
H(A|B,X=x) = H(A|X=x) + H(B|X=x) - H(B|X=x) = H(A|X=x).
$$
But then
$$
H(A|B) \geq H(A|BX) = \sum_x p_x H(A|X=x) \geq 0
$$
And so,
$$
I(A:B) = H(A) - H(A|B) \leq H(A) - \sum_x p_x H(A)_{\sigma_x} \leq H(A).
$$
We can do the same argument for $I(A:B) = H(B) - H(B|A)$ so the result holds.

Comment: very nice trick passing through the purification to show that $H(A|B)\ge0$. In hindsight, this reminds me the discussions about state merging, which are all about how the negativity of $H(A|B)$ can be exploited to perform entanglement (if I remember correctly). So also from that point of view, we must have $H(A|B)\ge0$ for separable states

Comment: Thanks. Note though that the X system isn't purifying the state, it's just a classical register that keeps track of which term in the convex combination you have. Perhaps one can do something similar with a purification but I don't immediately see it. The upshot of this proof is that negative conditional entropy is a sufficient condition for bipartite entanglement (it's only necessary if the state is pure).

Comment: ok, I finally had a chance of going through this more carefully. You're right of course. I do wonder why this trick works though. It feels like you're removing the discord contributions from $H(A|B)$ and finding it to still be positive, by making the various states in the separable decomposition "artificially distinguishable" via addition of an additional classical register